# How to stop a page from loading with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, postbackurl

I have a Button with PostBackUrl.
Also I have assigned a function to its onclientclick method in which some page logic were written including a couple of validation rules.
if whole page were not valid this method returns False but I can not stop page. I have tried document.execCommand('Close') and Window.Stop() but no success.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return DoLogic()"  PostBackUrl="http://google.com" Class="btn_submit"/>
```

DoLogic:

```
function DoLogic() {

if (ValidateForm()) {
blah blah blah
return true;
}
else {
alert("Has Error");
return false;
}
```

ValidateForm:

```
function ValidateForm(){
if (haserror)  
{  
return false; 
} 
return true; 
}
```

Comment: Try to set `onclientclick="return DoLogic()"` like this.

Comment: window.stop() is lowercase, which does matter. i'm not sure if stop() still works like it used to. a good throw "stop!"; should also do the trick for the current script block.

Comment: @maketest, 
I changed it to <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclientclick="return DoLogic()" PostBackUrl="http://www.google.com" Class="btn_submit"/>
However it stops the page from redirecting, but it stops the page even if the Validation returns True value!

Comment: See my answer for some insight on how to use PostBackUrl

Comment: @amirmoradifard try updating your onclientclick attribute to `"if (!DoLogic()) return false;"` instead of `"return DoLogic()"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.preventDefault()` method on your event. This will stop the default action of a page load when the button is clicked.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation

You can also `return false;` inside your `DoLogic()`. This will stop the page load as well.

```
onclientclick="return DoLogic()"
```

Then in your function:

```
function DoLogic(){
    //blah blah blah
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you're doing all of this and are still having problems, try adding this to your button:

```
onclick="javascript:return false"
```

**UPDATE FROM OP**

Your code isn't working because in the if statement you `return true;` and false only gets returned if the shit hits the fan (ie an error). You need to return false everytime. OR use the `.preventDefault()` like I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I am returning False, but Page still redirecting to the PostBackURL address

Comment: Yes, but still no success.

Comment: I used your and 'Dr. Wily's Apprentice' suggestion and they both works fine. 
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I've read that the PostBackUrl can give you trouble, and especially in this case because it looks like you're using it wrong. I'm thinking you may be confused about what PostBackUrl does. It is an attribute used in Cross-Page posting. If you are trying to redirect the user to a different page when the postback is completed, use `Response.Redirect()` in the code-behind or use an `<asp:HyperLink>` tag instead.

There should be no reason for which you could not use `Response.Redirect()`. Just add it to the end of your script in the code-behind. If the client-side validation returns false, the life-cycle will not reach the server-side anyway.

All-in-all it looks like you have at least three errors in that control:

1. You definitely need the `return` part of the `OnClientClick` attribute.
2. You need to change the `Class` attribute to `CssClass`.
3. You probably need to use something other than `PostBackUrl` on that button.

---

You can read more about it here:

- [MSDN - Button.PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx)

---

### To elaborate . . .

If you are trying to send a user to another site when the code is finished executing, the `PostBackUrl` attribute cannot be used in the manner you have shown us. For instance, in your example, even if it did work, the user would likely see this:

[image]

Comment: Neither of Response.redirect or Hyperlink is an option here. I have to use PostBackURL.

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you please take a look and guess what could be wrong here?

Comment: @amirmoradifard Are you trying to redirect the user to a URL or did you replace your local file path with "http://google.com" for the purposes of this question?

Comment: I have changed it to google. Actually the code is <asp:Button ID="btnMembershipSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return MembershipCalculateAmount()"  PostBackUrl="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" Class="btn_submit"/>
Clicking the button should post form to WorldPay website. So redirect and Hyperlink can not be used for this purpose.